# MDAC 2.8/WDAC 6.0 on Windows Server 2008 IIS 7

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, asp-classic

What I am trying to do is simple. I have some Classic ASP with include headers like the following referencing MDAC 2.5:

```
METADATA TYPE="TypeLib" NAME="Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.5 Library"        UUID="{00000205-0000-0010-8000-00AA006D2EA4}" VERSION="2.5"
```

Now I am trying to call this same include file on a Windows 2008 box with IIS 7 using MDAC 2.8 with this:

```
METADATA TYPE="typelib" NAME="Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library"        UUID="{2A75196C-D9EB-4129-B803-931327F72D5C}" VERSION="2.8"
```

My question is, why does this not work anymore? Has the tag reference changed? I ran MDAC checker and everything is installed correctly. What am I missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No one has run into this issue with legacy code on a Win2008 box?

Comment: it seems that you are alone. A tip use MDAC Utility: Component Checker, http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=8F0A8DF6-4A21-4B43-BF53-14332EF092C9&displaylang=en

Answer (score 1):

Actually they both do work - MDAC 2.8/WDAC 6.0 comes with Windows 2008 but either statement will work on the top of your code. The problem was actually non-related to this.

I know, I know, dumb mistake.